# how to tkinter slider

Tags: tkinter

I've been searching for this problem for a while now, but I just couldn't find this one specific question.

So, I'm trying to link my text entry with the scales, but I don't know how.

**** due to solved, code removed

I'm thankful for any answers!!! :)

Comment: First of You should provide a [mre], second do You need to work it both ways or do You need to only have the slider change the value, because if You need the slider to change value only, why don't You use a Label. Third, there is a widget [Spinbox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_spinbox.htm) which maybe is what You need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: problem solved. Did delete bc has nothing to do with a general answer. code deleted. personal belonging to the person who opened the threat.

For questions ask the question maker. thanks.

Comment: No problem @doodie

Comment: Try fixing the indentation of your functions. Indent them like ```def __init__()```

Comment: @doodie Please check out the answer.

Comment: @doodie ~ Consider marking this as the correct answer if this answered your question correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Answer (score 0):

If the scale and the entry widget share the same variable, they will be kept in sync.

```python
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar(value=120)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=120, to=220, orient="horizontal", variable=var)

entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
scale.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]